# Is this so-called "asbestos black mastic"?

Tags: asbestos

Originally, I just want to find what was the manufacture of old 8x8 tiles to exact match, then use same tile to fill a 10 sqft empty space which cabinets removed in the floor.

My bad is that I used Dremel to cut grout then used chisel to pull out 4-5 tiles, also grinding a few small oarts of black mastic parts to try to find some marks which may show manufacture info. Meanwhile, I used dry/wet vacuum to absorb dust.

Then I realize there is black mastic underneath the tile, which may be related to asbestos since house was built in 1968.Tiles seem like ceramic not asbestos. Just concerned about black mastic, is there any luck mastic is black but not asbestos? The previous owner disclosed there are asbestos tiles in some closets but didn't mention kitchen flooring.

I thought normally asbestos tile and black mastic should come together, does this mean previous owners have disturbed them and replaced them with ceramic but not removed adhesive?

If there are asbestos black mastic after lab test. Does this mean I disturbed them already? Do I need an airborne test?

(click to enlarge images)
[image: white tile, brown color inside,thinset underneath, then there are black adhesives]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Results were back. they are not asbestos. Alarm released.Thank you for your help

Comment: A:Don't Panic. Most actual health issues with asbestos are from chronic exposure, not a one-time careless mistake. B: given the age of the house, get the mastic tested, there's no way to tell "with or without asbestos" by eyeball.

Comment: Not an *exact* duplicate, but this should (hopefully) calm you down a bit: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/217202/asbestos-exposure-need-help/217210#217210

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody can identify asbestos simply by looking at a picture.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thx a lot, but after saw Lee Sam's answer, still panic a little bit, my exposure area is very small, but does it mean they already be disturbe and friable? then I have to wipe out all surface I think since I can not turn off furnace since temperature is not warm enough?

Comment: @Freeman, any knowledge, if they are not ACM, what black mastic could be?

Comment: Your best bet, especially if you're going to be pulling more up, is to get them tested for asbestos content. It'll cost you, but you'll know one way or the other. If they're not, then you've nothing to worry about at all. If they are, you'll probably want to have an asbestos abatement company remove the rest to minimize any additional spread. They can probably work in a deal on clean up from whatever minor mess you may have made so far. Anything else is just speculation.

Comment: @FreeMan, thx, right, I am waiting for lab results.

Comment: Not all black mastic is asbestos filled, some is asphalt but the tiles have asbestos. The only way to know is through testing I have worked with both and after 50 years testing is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks, I will keep posting about results